# IEF with custom profile2 type not work

Tags: 7, users, entities

I have node reference field attached to profile2 type entity and I can't add new entity to user profile. Even as admin (uid=1).

See my screenshoots for details

view user profile

[image: view user profile]

add node to user profile

[image: add node to user profile]

save changes and see no changes at all

[image: save changes and see no changes at all]

Big WTF for me. Thought is is permissions related but why it's not working for superuser also. When I'm using IEF with node to node reference all is working.

I need advice how to resolve this issue. What check first, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No chance for working: https://www.drupal.org/node/2043177

!@#!@#!